# Cannot pass array to angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, directive, input-mask

Cannot pass an array to input mask plugin in Angular. 
Maybe somebody can help me with this.

```
angular.module('myproject.directives').   
directive('inputMask', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            inputMask: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
            $(el).inputmask(attrs.inputMask);
        }
    };
});

<input type="text" input-mask="{'mask': '9{4} 9{4} 9{4} 9{4}[9]', 'autoUnmask': 'true'}" />
```

Comment: Problem could be single quotes.

Comment: The '@' property tells the directive to expect a string, so you can pass it a string and then manipulate it into an array the directive understands in the link function. What you show in your `input-mask` attribute doesn't look like an array, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute value will return a string , not an object as is needed to pass to the plugin

You can switch the quotes around so that the string is valid JSON and then parse the json to an object

```
<input type="text" input-mask='{"mask": "9{4} 9{4} 9{4} 9{4}[9]", "autoUnmask": "true"}' />
```

JS

```
.directive('inputMask', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            inputMask: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
          var mask =JSON.parse(attrs.inputMask);
           $(el).inputmask(mask);
        }
    };
})
```

But realistically this would be much simpler not putting the string in the html and passing an object reference from your controller to the isolated scope instead

Answer (score 0):

Just use `scope.$eval` method to execute the expression in `inputMask` attribute:

```
angular.module('myproject.directives')  
.directive('inputMask', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            inputMask: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
            $(el).inputmask(scope.$eval(attrs.inputMask));
        }
    };
});

<input type="text" input-mask="{'mask': '9{4} 9{4} 9{4} 9{4}[9]', 'autoUnmask': 'true'}" />
```